# how to align Armenian text?

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

I want to align text written in Armenian, but using `\justify`  command doesn't align it completely. There remain some lines which are not fully aligned. How can I fix this ?
Thank you

Comment: Hi, and welcome to TeX.SE! Could you be so kind and edit your post with an example (ideally minimal) showing what you're doing, and, if possible, what the result is? Thanks!

Comment: In particular, do please share the following pieces of information: Do you compile your document under pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX? Which document class do you employ? Which fonts do you use, and how are they loaded?

Comment: justification is the default, there are almost no circumstances when you need tio use ragged2e's `\justification` command (`\justify` like `\center` is for use as an environment). In any language if you have a word tex can not hyphenate you may get an overfull box warning and text in the margin, you can tell tex how to hyphenate the word or allow white space to stretch more, it depends on the details of each case.  Make sure you have the language set correctly, if you try to hyphenate Armenian with the default English hyphenation rules, it will not work well.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your responses, I am using online latex overleaf, (I'm new to latex and I actually don't know which type I use, maybe pdf Latex... I use \documentclass[12pt]{article}

Comment: yes pdflatex is the default on overleaf. But you have still given no hint about the cause of the issue. Have you specified armenian language anywhere in your docuement? Are the words that are sticking in to the margin normal text or unbreakable things like `\fbox{this}` ?